# Update export variables from the modules

Tags: javascript, export

I need to transfer some variables from one script to another in ohter HTML section, and this new section can CHANGE that variable.
The problem is that this change doesnt update.

For example, let see this code in my MAIN HTML:

```
let array = [{name: 'John', ranking: 1000}, {name: 'Scott', ranking: 1200}, {name: 'Emma', ranking: 800}] // etc...
export { array }
```

Now, in other script that is in OTHER HTML:

```
import { array } from /.mainLocation/main.js
let newPlayer = {name: 'Richard', ranking: 1232}
array.push(newPlayer);
console.log(array) // [{name: 'John', ranking: 1000}, {name: 'Scott', ranking: 1200}, {name: 'Emma', ranking: 800}, {name: 'Richard', ranking: 1232}]
// Is updated
```

BUT in my main HTML/script it doesnt update.

How can i update the variables beetwen the codes??
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set up the variables in HTML and import the variables into js, but it would have to update in HTML and the js file would be importing the variables constantly. Your more likely to be successful importing them from html.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The things is that i have a few HTMLs, everyone with his js code. I dont know how to pass the variable from the HTML to another HTML.